# Any linear function sooner or later dominates a log function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $k \in \mathbb N$ $\exists K$ such that $\forall k \ge K$ $k > a+b \ln(k)$? In other words any linear function sooner or later dominates a log function?

Comment: See Corollary 2.2 here: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/growth.pdf

Comment: Look at the limit of $\frac{\ln(k)}{k}$ with l'Hospital

Comment: So I guess we can not learn much about how sequences $ln(n)$ and $n$ are related before we study l'Hospital rule, which requires knowledge of derivatives, which are in their turn are based on understanding of sequences and their convergences. So if you teach this subject after l'Hospital is digested you need to revisit sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $k>0$, let $k=e^x$ for some $x$. We have to prove $\frac{a+bx}{e^x}$ tends to zero as $x$ tends to $\infty$.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a+bx}{e^x}=\frac{a}{e^x}+b\frac{x}{e^x}=0$$
Computing this limit is straight-forward using L'Hopital's rule.